# how to override overflow:hidden?

Tags: css

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r2mtA/2/) here.

As the parent-parent node of pink div, the blue div included the css style `overflow:hidden`, which is essential in my project for other parts of content.

But now I have to show the pink square across the border, it seems a part of it was overlapped because of it parent's `overflow:hidden`. What should I do if I want to make it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* possible. If you declare `overflow:hidden` on an element, *all* child elements have to obey this rule.

What you can do is to move the box out and position it accordingly:

```
<div class="paper">
    <div class="container">    
    </div>
    <div class="box">    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** to you parent class `.papaer` `overflow:hidden` and

**add this css**

```
.paper:after{
    content:'';
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r2mtA/3/)**

Comment: thanks, but [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r2mtA/4/), it seems not the same as before while I adding content to blue div...

Comment: now define your ".paper" class this "word-break: break-word;" demo http://jsfiddle.net/r2mtA/5/

Comment: It's closing, but not the same as the original style of overflow:hidden because the exceeded parts of word should be correctly hidden, is that right?